# Is it possible draw CGContext in blocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgcontext

On IOS, I have a NSArray stores `blocks` that drawing something on the UIView, for example :

```
^(CGContextRef ctx) {
    // drawing rectangle
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);
    CGContextStrokeRect(ctx, rect);
};
```

There would be several blocks stored in the array, and I expect those block execute sequently when `drawRect` got invoked, here's my `drawRect`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // execute blocks 
    for(NSDictionary * task in drawTaskQueue)
    {
        DrawTaskBlock block = [task objectForKey:@"block"];
        block(args, UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    }
}
```

But when I run the code, I'm sure the blocks got executed without any error, but nothing is showing up. Did I missed something ?

Comment: How is `DrawTaskBlock` defined?

Comment: Seems that your block is running on a background thread, try to run it on main thread, this is the only thread which allows UI updates.

Comment: @azimov The call is coming from `drawRect`, so it's on the correct thread.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yep, I've missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the block that you are passing expects a single parameter of type `CGContextRef`, while the calling code is passing two arguments - `args` and `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`.

Since Objective-C does not check the cast, your blocks end up running with a wrong graphic context, causing undefined behavior.

To fix this problem you need to make sure that the "signature" of the block matches the signature of the block type to which you cast it, i.e. `DrawTaskBlock`. The signature must include the proper type of the `args` parameter, even if none of your blocks is using it.